# How to Convert a Date to Django Timezone Aware Datetime

Tags: python, django, datetime

I am trying to convert a DateTime with the UTC time zone to Django datetime that respects the time zone of my date.

Here is my `settings.py`:

```py
TIME_ZONE = 'US/Pacific'

USE_TZ = True
```

Here is the date I am trying to convert to the right time zone for django: `datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 20, 8, 55, 48, 846000)`

I used the `make_aware` function provided by Django but I can see the date isn't converted to the time zone in my `settings.py` when I save the Django Modal with a DateTime field

```py
from django.utils.timezone import make_aware
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/timezones/)

> When time zone support is enabled (USE_TZ=True), Django uses time-zone-aware datetime objects. If your code creates datetime objects, they should be aware too. In this mode, the example above becomes:

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I understand that using a time zone other than UTC is problematic. What will happen to all the objects and their datetimes if I change the timezone in my settings to UTC?